# Is it possible to do branching in SVN with a GIANT repository?

Tags: svn, repository, branch

We currently have a GIANT SVN repository. This thing is probably 5+ GB.
Lately we've been making an attempt to clean up some broken, outdated code, however in the meantime we are still needing to do pushes to our test environment.

Obviously we should be doing some sort of branching, however, the way I always understood branching was that it created a copy of your ENTIRE repository for each branch. Obviously that's more space than I'm really wanting to take up.

Is there a way to do it for individual project folders?

If you need any clarification in what I'm talking about, just ask.

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, the way I always understood [Subversion] branching was that it created a copy of your ENTIRE repository for each branch.

No, Subversion doesn't.  It creates pointers to the trunk of the repository.

As you make changes, only the changes are saved as part of the branch.